# ActiveAdmin add global navigation menu for belongs_to sidebar link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Between the `user` and the `article` resource i have the `belongs_to` and `has_many` relationship. For the nesting in the admin panel i used AA `belongs_to` while registering the resources:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
ActiveAdmin.register Article do
       belongs_to :user
end
```

I understand that Articles cannot be in the global navigation anymore because they need the corresponding `user` id. But how can i add the global navigation 
menu when visit the `Article` page? Right now i only see an Atricle entry which redirects to the same page?

```
sidebar "Details for User", only: :show do
   ul do
    li link_to "Article List",admin_user_articles_path(user)
   end                 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK if i only would ve read the  [documentation](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#belongs-to)a bit more careful (:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article
    menu false
    belongs_to :user
    navigation_menu :default
end
```